# Magento 2 - core/resource getConnection()

Tags: magento2

I have the following Magento 1 code and i would like to know the Magento 2 equivalent of the code.

I've looked around on the web but unable to find a proper solution.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')
```

I was able to find the function getConnection() at \Magento\Framework\DB\Query but it does not take any parameters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please let me know if you have issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    protected $_resource;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
        ) {
            $this->_resource = $resource;
        }
```

Inside function,

```
$connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
$tablename = $connection->getTableName('sales_order');
$query = "your query";
$connection->query($query);
```